# What did Ikta mean when he said "...Right now, you’re really red..."?

Tags: alderamin-on-the-sky

Towards the end of episode 4 of the anime, Ikta says

> “Yo, Yatori, there’s something important I need to tell you. You might
>   already know it, though… Right now, you’re really red, you know?”

Which makes sense in context for Yatorie: red hair, red blood, adrenaline, etc.

What doesn't make sense is when he said it to the princess a few minutes later:

> “And by the way, I won’t mention it anywhere else, but I’ll tell you privately in secret…. Princess, right now, you’re really red.”

What does it mean when Ikta said that to the princess?  Was he trying to flirt?  Was he trying to look cool?

Quotes came from [here](https://www.baka-tsuki.org/project/index.php?title=Tenkyou_no_Alderamin:Volume_1_Chapter_4), which seems to be a slightly different story than the anime.

Comment: Considering the situation, I'd assume a joke to comfort the princess fell flat?

Comment: Yeah that's what happened, though I don't understand how it's a compliment or a flirt.  I suspect it has to do with the history or context of the story or backstory.